# How Add HTTPS support to Mirth Connect Server？

Tags: https

Integrating an HTTPS interface in hospitals using Mirth Connect communication server

the HTTPS support is missing in the free version

The problem with the free Mirth Connect version remains, in that it is not capable of forwarding outbound HL7 messages directly to an HTTPS endpoint on the server ,I need everyone's help！

Stunnel is an application that allows to forward data from one socket to another, in particular to forward the outgoing traffic from an HTTP socket to an HTTPS socket.
Additional context
https://www.stunnel.org/index.html

Comment: Free Mirth Connect version is not able to start an HTTPS listener. But it is able to start an HTTPS sender. I am not quite sure which one do you need. But as you are speaking about "forwarding" I believe is the second one, which is totally doable.

Comment: Can both send and receive？

Comment: HTTP Sender makes mirth to act as a client. HTTP Listener makes mirth to act like a server. You can, for example, create a channel, with one HTTP Listener as a source (only plain http in free version), and use an HTTP Sender inside a destination (able to speak HTTPS)

Comment: Receive and transmit

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/jonbartels/8abd121901eb930f46245d9ef0f5710e describes several options:

> The built-in MC HTTP Sender connector will do HTTPS if:
>
> ...
>
> The built-in MC HTTP Listener connector will not do SSL directly. A plugin or a proxy is necessary.
>
> ...
>
> Mirth has a commercial SSL extension - https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/integration-engine
>
> Zen Healthcare IT has a an SSL extension with up-front pricing at - https://consultzen.com/zen-ssl-extension/
>
> Innovar has published an AWS instance with SSL support at - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-rrvfqfm5vxbtk?sr=0-2&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa
>
> ...
>
> Channel code - You can use tools like Apache HTTP Commons or OKHttp in MC and use that code to deal with SSL